# Tracking analytics on the submission of a form

Tags: javascript, jquery, analytics

I use Adobe analytics to track form data on the submit process. I have a simple for like this:

```
<form action="index.php" name="frm" id="frm" method="post">
<div id="div1">
....
</div>
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

I use this in order to track the data on submission process and add values to some variables onsubmission process using this

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
    $("#frm").submit(function(){
                s=s_gi('name');
                s.linkTrackVars="pageName,prop1";
                s.pageName = 'test';
                s.prop1 = 'frm';
                s.tl(true,'o','link', null,'navigate');
                }); 
</script>
```

When I press the button it seems to execute fine and I can see the global variables but I can see the new variables I have set on submission process. From analytics side how can I understand that the event of submission happened successfully? Using the s.tl() I expect when I click to submit button I receive information for the custom link.

Comment: I expected a _but I can't see_  -  what does s.tl do and what is the exact problem? The code you have (preventDefault()) will stop the submission and ONLY call s.tl

Comment: Both preventDefault and return false will stop the form from being submitted. If that is what you want, I do not understand the question